# Minimax algorithm is the tree implemented as it should be?

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I want to create a minimax search which has a depth of 3, each node will have two childs, does the code properly represent that,  is this the correct implementation, or am I doing something wrong?

```
    static int miniMaxAlgorithm(int node, int depth, bool maxPlayer)
    {
        int eval;
        int maxEval;
        int minEval;

        if (depth == 0)
        {            
             return node; // static evaluation to be returned          
        }

        if (maxPlayer)
        {

            maxEval = int.MaxValue;

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                eval = miniMaxAlgorithm(i, depth - 1, maxPlayer = false);
                maxEval = Math.Max(maxEval, eval);
                Console.WriteLine(maxEval);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", depth);
            }
         
            return maxEval;
        }

        else
        {
            minEval = int.MinValue;

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                eval = miniMaxAlgorithm(i, depth - 1, maxPlayer = true);
                minEval = Math.Min(minEval, eval);
                Console.WriteLine(minEval);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", depth);
            }
            return minEval;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: 14 Console.Writelines will appear in the terminal ( presumably for all the nodes except the root). I am trying to establish whether the tree with be structured as expected and that they are not in some other sort of order.

Answer (score 0):

It looks alright but unfinished to me. What are you planning to do with it? If you are playing a game for example then you want to make the move right before the

```
eval = miniMaxAlgorithm(i, depth - 1, maxPlayer = false);
```

And then undo the move right after that.

If you want to return the best move you also need to make some adjustments. But based on the pseudo code for Minimax found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) the foundation of your implementation looks correct.

However, for easier readability, I would consider the [Negamax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negamax) function instead which might also make things easier down the road. Depending on what you plan to do with this.

Comment: Thank you Eli! I am working on some cheating hangman game ( where the computer has access to a list of words belonging to a word family).                                                    
When the player makes a guess, ideally I would like the computer to look ahead a move or two  and to consider whether to choose the biggest possible word family or not  and make a decision based on some evaluation, what is the most promising.